# Contact Page redirect to 404 page in magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, contact-us

I recently checked my Contact page and found out it redirects to a 404 page.

Using the below url, it works fine:

> http://192.168.0.33/test/contact/index/index

but using below url I get not redirected to contact page

> http://192.168.0.33/test/contact/

Anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: It should definitely work in theory. Please see this: http://www.jalpanam.com/magento/default-controller-in-magento-2/
You have everything setup as shown in the link?

Comment: Rajeev i am using magneto 2.2 default contact page . there is no need to in any layout

Comment: There is no layout files in the given link.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot but had this exact issue with Magento 1. Pulled 90% of my hair out to find it was to do with a .htaccess rule I had added.

SiteGround told me to add the following info to help with security which is what broke the functionality.
[Link Here](https://www.siteground.com/kb/prevent-malicious-bots-visiting-website/)

So check if you have added any of these rules that could be causing some conflict